# ReactJS how to wait for all API calls to be ended in componentDidMount of simple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using latest react and very basic app which calls 3rd party service API which actually is not well designed in meaning of following.
I have to execute one call which return list and then have to iterate and call other end point to get data for item from list and then again in data have new list for which I have to call 3rd API end point.
After I receive all data I combined it to one items array and place it in state in `componentDidMount` function but this final step works only if I surround it with `setTimeout`.

Is there some elegant way to do that?

I'm using `fetch` and really pure react components, have my own simple service from where I call API, here is some code parts...

```
    items[tag].sensors = [];
    API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, tag).then(links => {

    Object.keys(links.link).forEach(link => {
        API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, link).then(objLink => {
            Object.keys(objLink.link).forEach(function (key) {
                let obj = objLink.link[key];
                if (obj && obj.type === 'sensor') {
                    API.getSensorNames(sessionData, key).then(response => {
                        const sensor =  response.sensor;
                        // some sensor calculations....
                        items[tag].sensors.push(sensor);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
// this part only works if it's surrounded with timeout
setTimeout(function() {
    let processedItems = [];
    for (var key in items) {
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            processedItems.push(items[key]);
        }
    }
    self.setState({
        items: processedItems
    });

}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @SLaks yeah right, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, You can use Promise to wait until you get values from the API call, therefore you will put your code in function like this

```
function prepareItems() {
  items[tag].sensors = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, tag).then(links => {
      Object.keys(links.link).forEach(link => {
        API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, link).then(objLink => {
          Object.keys(objLink.link).forEach(function(key) {
            let obj = objLink.link[key];
            if (obj && obj.type === "sensor") {
              API.getSensorNames(sessionData, key).then(response => {
                const sensor = response.sensor;
                // some sensor calculations....
                items[tag].sensors.push(sensor);
                // whenever you set resolve it will end the promise
                //and pass the result it to the then function
                resolve(items)
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

and use `then` to get the result from the prepareItems function after its resolved

```
prepareItems().then(items => {
//Do what ever you want with prepared item
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using `async/await` operators.

These operators allows you to wait until the response is ready. 
You can use this kind of helper function.

```
getItems = async (...) => {
  ...
  items[tag].sensors = []
  const links = await API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, tag)

  Object.keys(links.link).forEach(async (link) => {
    const objLink = await API.getObjects(sessionData, userDetails, link)

    Object.keys(objLink.link).forEach(async (key) => {
      let obj = objLink.link[key]
      if (obj && obj.type === 'sensor') {
        const response = await API.getSensorNames(sessionData, key)
        const sensor = response.sensor
        items[tag].sensors.push(sensor)
      }
    })
  })

  this.setState({ items })
}
```

Also you can see this great [documentation](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html).